# How do I convert float('nan') to binary in python?

Tags: python, binary, floating-point, nan

The title says it all. I know pickle can do it, but I don't really want to open a file just to convert a single number. I want to take float('nan') and send it over the network in its binary format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('d', float('nan'))
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f'
```

if you want a double-precision (8-byte) binary representation in little-endian format.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html for all details of how to use big-endian and/or single-precision (4-byte) format instead.

Comment: I swear I learn something new every time I find one of your answers.

Comment: @Alex, that gladdens my heart, thanks for sharing!-)

Comment: A minor tweak: I'd suggest `'<d'` for the `struct.pack` format, to ensure little-endianness.  As it stands, the endianness of the result depends on the platform.